# How to cache and use gradle plugins locally?

Tags: caching, gradle, gradle-plugin

I am trying to build my application with limited access to internet with Gradle.

I was successfully able to use normal jars with

```
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
...
```

and populating `~\.m2\repository` with appropriate files.

But I also have statements like

```
plugins {
    id 'org.hidetake.ssh' version '2.4.0'
}
```

in my `build.gradle`. When build, I get the following error

```
Error resolving plugin [id: 'org.hidetake.ssh', version: '2.4.0']
> Could not GET 'https://plugins.gradle.org/api/gradle/2.9/plugin/use/org.hidetake.ssh/2.4.0'.
   > Connection to https://plugins.gradle.org refused
```

Apparently, Gradle is trying to get plugin from Internet, which is prohibited.

How can I cache this plugin?

On my another machine, which has full internet access, I found directories like

`.gradle\caches`

but it has some strange hash subdirectories, which I am not sure how to use. Copying of `modules-2` directory from another machine didn't help.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose, it's not possible with the new plugins DSL, because in that case, plugin is specified by it's global unique id and version, which are not stored in your cache.

You can use for that some local plugin repository with required additional Plugin Marker Artifact, read about it [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:custom_plugin_repositories).

Or just don't use plugins dsl and declare your dependencies in plain old way with `apply plugin: 'plugin_name'` and storing required jars in your local repository the same way, it's done with you project dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

you add the file `settings.gradle`

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
    }
}
```

and now it will onlz try to resolve plugins from `~/.m2/repository/`